# How add a property to the http header with customizable name

Tags: java, get, http-proxy

I want to send my HTTP get request to a proxy who will forward it to the destination I really want to talk to.
I need to send it like this:

> GET https://proxy.com:1234/something
>   DESTINATION_URL:https://destination.com:1234/something"

So here I am telling in DESTINATION_URL to Proxy where I want my request to be sent.

Currenty I am using Java code to send request to send request to Proxy. This needs to be updated to include destination URL

```
WebResource webResource = proxyClient.resource(ProxyURL);
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
ClientResponse response = WebResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.cl‌​ass);
```

Can I do it like:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("DESTINATION_URL",<destination_url>).acce‌​pt("application/json‌​").get(ClientRespons‌​e.class);
```

Comment: Currenty I am using following Java code to send request to send request to Proxy. This needs to be updated to include destination URL
WebResource webResource = proxyClient.resource(ProxyURL);

webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Hi @bated - Is something not clear?

Comment: Can I do it like:
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("DESTINATION_URL",<destination_url>).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebResource.header(String, Object)`](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.8/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#header(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). So in your case:

```
WebResource webResource = proxyClient.resource(ProxyURL);
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
webResource.header("DESTINATION_URL", <destination_url>);
ClientResponse response = WebResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.cl‌​ass);
```